# Finding an element using name/type attribute in DefaultSelenium

Tags: c#, selenium, attributes, click, submit

I want to click the submit button using DefaultSelenium.Is there a way to find an element using name or type??

Ex:

```
<input type="submit" name="xyz:j_id123" value="Next" class="btnSubmit" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved using XPATH selector as given below:

```
  Selenium.Click("//div/input[@class='btnSubmit']");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
//input[@name='xyz:j_id123']
//input[@value='Next']
//input[@name='name_attribute' and @value='value_attribute']
```